# Var clojure.core/unquote-splicing is unbound error while passing list elements to hash-map

Tags: clojure

I am trying to create a map from an interleaved list and running into errors. Here is what I am doing:

```
(interleave ['a 'b] [1 2])
```

gives the list (a 1 b 2).

If I want to create a hash-map from a bunch of elements, I can do

```
(hash-map 'a 1 'b 2)
```

Combining the two together,

```
(hash-map ~@(interleave ['a 'b] [1 2]))
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Var clojure.core/unquote-splicing is unbound. (repl-1:2)
```

How do I pass the elements of the list to hash-map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `apply`:

```
(apply hash-map (interleave ['a 'b] [1 2]))
```

`apply` applies a function to a seq of arguments; type `(doc apply)` at the REPL for details.

`~@` is one of the two companions to the syntax-quote, written as backtick, the other being `~`:

```
`(~(+ 1 2) ~@[2 1])
; => (3 2 1)
```

The three are useful mostly for writing macros; you cannot use `~` and `~@` outside of syntax-quote.